# Copy script adds non-ASCII characters to the end of the new file

Tags: python, character-encoding, utf-16, copying

Im doing example 17 in LPTHW 3.6 and the study drill asks to attempt to shorten the code, I don't understand why my solution to shortening the code works seemingly fine but adds squares to the end of the new file.

```
from sys import argv 
script, from_file, to_file = argv
print(f"Copying from {from_file} to {to_file}")
indata = open(from_file).read()
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)
print(">>>>out_file", repr(out_file))
print("Alright, all done.")
out_file.close()
```

I expected the output file  to be an exact copy of the input file but instead it is a copy of the input file with 2 unidentified characters that show up as squares in notepad appended to the end of the string.

From_file and to_file included here https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Z_VoXpHRaVQVN0qfmF2wqoQ2EzVtots

Comment: I tried your code on my computer and didn't get added text. Can you post your `from_file` somewhere? Also, you should close the `from_file` after opening it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Z_VoXpHRaVQVN0qfmF2wqoQ2EzVtots both text files are there. Also when I try to add clsoing the from_file at the end I get an error saying I cant close a string object.

Comment: Interesting - looking at your files, both appear to be encoded as UTF-16. in the original, the end of line is `b'\r\x00\n\x00'`.  This would be correct for a Windows machine using UTF-16 as its default encoding I think: the UTF-16 encoding of '\r' or '\n' is the ASCII character followed by a null byte (`b'\x00'`).  The EOL in the output file is `b'\r\n\x00\r\n\x00'`: here it looks as '\r\n' is being treated as a single character, so instead of `b'\r\x00\n\x00'` we have `b'\r\n\x00'`.  Anyway, you don't need to worry about this as a beginner - it's for anyone else who wants to answer.

Comment: One possibility is that the file might have been saved in an application that doesn't work well with unicode.  If you run the script again, to a different outfile, and open the new outfile in an editor such as Notepad++, TextPad or SublimeText or VSCode (but _not_ Notepad) do you still see the unexpected characters?